# Strategy for File System Permissions On KVM Shared Folder

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, zfs, linux-kvm, qemu

I have a Ubuntu/KVM hypervisor environment that has access (via NFS) to ZFS data sets (aka file systems).   I have been hosting the VM images on a ZFS file system which, although not the fastest thing in the world, does make them very stable.

What I would like to do is give the guest VMs direct access to a ZFS file system by using a KVM shared feature to give VMs access to a ZFS data set and mounting it inside the guest.  There are two reasons for this:

1. I am hoping for a speed improvement because only one filesystem structure -- ZFS -- will be maintained instead of ext4 over ZFS which is what I have now.
2. I want the users to be able to access the snapshot feature of ZFS.

I have managed to mount the volumes as described but I haven't been able to mount them so they are writable.  Searching the web I find that the effective user name is libvirt+ but I haven't been able to find a **chmod** setting to the target file system that will work.

Can someone point me to a guide about how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the tactical part of your question, it sounds like you're using NFS to do the guest/host sharing. Then it just comes down to an NFS permissions question. On the host, make sure it is shared read/write, like `zfs set sharenfs="rw=@w.x.y.z/N" tank` where `w.x.y.z/N` is the set of IP addresses that you want to give access to this share. For a more complete example, see [here](https://www.hiroom2.com/2016/05/18/ubuntu-16-04-share-zfs-storage-via-nfs-smb/).

But also, about your goals:

1. If the host stores VM disk files on ZFS and the guest uses ext4 on top of that, ZFS is unlikely to add much "filesystem overhead" in terms of performance. After all, KVM will only rarely (if ever) create new files in this mode, so metadata will not need to be updated in ZFS very often. My guess is that unless you are running a very performance-sensitive workload in the VMs (high throughput database, etc.), you will not notice much difference.
2. I don't know of any way to expose ZFS's snapshotting functionality to users of the guests. This can be done with zones on Solaris, and jails on FreeBSD, and maybe Docker / lxd / lxc on Linux (I'm not as certain about this one), but definitely not with KVM + QEMU. I think the only way to do this with KVM would be to give your users access to `zfs snapshot` on the host itself (either with direct SSH access or through a service or something).

There are other reasons why keeping data files on the host makes sense (consolidation, plus all the normal benefits of ZFS: easier backup, data integrity, place quotas and reservations, etc.), but I don't think those two will be particularly easier in your new configuration.